Import / Export database file
New to Android Kotlin programming.  I have simple app, and I would like to export and import the database to the phones download directory so can copy to computer if needed.
I have the following code.
The Export is working fine, the problem is when I try to import the database from download folder back into the database folder.
Do not understand why it is not working.
Any pointers would be great.  On the old windows phones, was easy to do this!!!
In the manifest file
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

in my MainActivity.kt
 //Export to downlod folder  (this works!!!!)
 private fun exportDbFile() {

    try {

        val dir = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Download/"
        )

        val success = true
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs()
          Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Directory created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        if (success) {
            //do nothing
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to create Directory", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
val DATA_DIRECTORY = Environment.getDataDirectory().absolutePath + "/mymeds2025.db"
        val dbFile = File(getDatabasePath("mymeds2025.db").absolutePath)
        Log.v("MainActivity", "a-" + dbFile);
        Log.v("TestActivity", "a-" + DATA_DIRECTORY);

        Toast.makeText(this,"a- " +dbFile,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        File(dbFile,"")
            .copyTo(File(dir, "mymeds2025.db"), true)

        Toast.makeText(this,"Database Exported!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    } catch (excep: Exception) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"$excep",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        Log.e("FILECOPYERROR>>>>",excep.toString())
        excep.printStackTrace()
    }
}

This is the part that is not working.
in the Logcat this message appears "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/mymeds2025.db: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)"
//Import the db from the download folder
private fun importDbFile() {

    try {
        //val dir = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Download/mymeds2025.db"
        val dir = "${Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()}/Download/mymeds2025.db"
        //)
        //"/data/data/com.rjenterprize.mymeds2025/databases/"
        val dbFile = File(getDatabasePath("mymeds2025.db").absolutePath)
        db.close()
        db.writableDatabase

       File(dir,"").copyTo(File(dbFile, ""), true)

        Toast.makeText(this,"Database Imported!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    } catch (excep: Exception) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"$excep",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        Log.e("FILECOPYERROR>>>>",excep.toString())
        excep.printStackTrace()
    }
}


depending on the android version you probably dont have access to the external directory but also you are using an empty string for your file path child File(dir,"") which you probably dont want. remove the empty string parameter to File(dir) to get the directory

In addition to the above problems, you do not have code in your export logic to close the database before making the copy. And, you specifically added code to open the database before doing the database import, which is risky. FWIW, I demonstrate import/export (or backup/restore) in the context of Room in this chapter of this free older book of mine. I make sure the database is closed before import/export and I use the Storage Access Framework to give the user control.

appreciate your reply, will have a look into it.   Just an update, I added the db.close() as you mentioned,  and I found that the app did not have permission checked.  once I did that, it now backups db and will restore the db.  Would be nice to find code that will pop up that permission screen when needed!!
